# How to use the atom text editor with git -java-

Tags: java, git, atom-editor

I am trying to use atom with git to work on a coding project with some class mates, for this particular project we are supposed to practice making different classes. I just pulled the most recent version of the project from git and I now see that they were successfully able to create new classes/tab-things but have it still within the main file. How do I do something like this in atom? I can't ask them because they use a different ide.

In the picture you can see different classes in drop-downs but its still within "project2" - how do I do this for another class and have it in a new drop down and upload it to git?

[image of what i'm looking at](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2Ehu.png)

Answer (score 0):

From the screen shot, those dropdowns appear to simply be diffs from the git log.  So if you want your changes to appear in a similar fashion, you'll need to create the classes (or additional files) and commit/push them.